# How to code yellow square, horizontal and vertical line in Step 10 in Make Your Own Mondrian Coder Project?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to code a Coder Project called Make your own Mondrian found here: [Coder Projects](https://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder-projects/projects/mondrian/)

In step 10, if you click on the link, it asks to code the bottom row of the Mondrian Art. I already coded the left part which is the blue box in the bottom row. I am having trouble coding the rest which is the right part in the bottom row. This is what I have coded so far:

**HTML:**

```
<body style="background-color:#f6f6f6;">
    <div id="painting">
        <div id="toprow">
            <div id="bigbox" class="red right"></div>
            <div id="divider1" class="black right"></div>
            <div id="topleftcolumn" class= "right">
            <div class="mediumbox"></div>
            <div id="divider2" class= "black"></div>
            <div class="mediumbox"></div>
         </div>

     <div id="painting">
        <div id="middlerow">
            <div id="topleftcolumn" class= " blue right">
                <div id="divider3" class= "black"></div>
                <div class="mediumbox1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>    

     <div id="painting">
         <div id="middlerow" class= "left blue">
             <div id="bottomleftcolumn" class= "left">
                 <div id="divider4" class= "black right"></div>
                 <div class="mediumbox1"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="painting">
         <div id="middlerow" class= "right">
             <div id="smallbox" class="red right"></div>
             <div id="bottomrightcolumn" class= "right">
                 <div id="divider4" class= "black left"></div>
                 <div class="mediumbox2"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#painting {
    background-color: #fff4db;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px #8d8d8d;
}

`red {
    background-color: red;   
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue; 
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;   
}
.black {
    background-color: black;   
}`.

#toprow {
    height: 290px;
    background-color: #fff4db
}

#bigbox {
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
}

#divider1 {
    height: 290px;
    width: 10px;
}

.mediumbox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
#divider2 {
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.left{
    float: left;
}

#divider3 {
    height: 10px;
    width: 400px;
}

#divider4 {
    height: 105px;
    width: 10px;
}

#topleftcolumn {    
    height:5px;
}

#bottomleftcollum {
    height:5px;
}

.mediumbox1 {
    width: 109px;
    height: 105px;
}

.mediumbox2 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 105px;
}

.mediumbox3 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 20px;
}

#divider5 {
    height: 105px;
    width: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a few things, i did it with floats since that is something you are trying to do:

```
// html

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="top-left"></div>
<div class="top-right"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="buttom-left"></div>
<div class="buttom-midle"></div>
<div class="buttom-rigth">
    <div class="buttom-left-in-top"></div>
    <div class="buttom-left-in-buttom"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

// and the css:

.top-left{
 float:left;
 background-color:#FFF4D8;  
 width:20%;
 height:calc(50vh - 40px);
 border: 10px solid #353535;
 }
 .top-right{
 float:right;
 background-color:#EB002B;  
 width:calc(80% - 40px);
 height:calc(50vh - 40px);
 border: 10px solid #353535;
 }
.buttom-left{
float: left;
width:20%;
height: calc(50vh - 40px);
border: 10px solid #353535;
background-color: #007bd8;
}
.buttom-midle {
float: left;
width:65%;
height: calc(50vh - 40px);
border: 10px solid #353535;
background-color: #fff4d8;
}
.buttom-rigth{
float: right;
height: calc(50vh - 40px);
width: calc(100% - 20% - 65% - 60px);
border: 10px solid #353535;
}
.buttom-left-in-top{
width:100%;
height: calc(50% - 10px);
background-color: #fff4d8;
border-bottom: 10px solid #353535;
}
.buttom-left-in-buttom{
width:100%;
height: calc(50% - 10px);
background-color: #ffd600;
border-top: 10px solid #353535;
}
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I do not actually know what floats are and I am just learning how to code Mondrian Art. I am sorry but I do not understand your code but I appreciate the help.

Comment: float is a property that takes an object out of normal flow of the web page and places on the left or right side of the page. For the bottom-right section if the painting i created a parent div and i floated to the right. inside that div i created another two divs, both of them will take a 100% of the width and 50% of the height of the parent div. and they will be stacked on top of each other. than you give a second div a background -color property of yellow.  you can study this code with chrome web-dev tools to kind of see how it works.

Comment: I am sort of confused because I never used floats and I also am not really sure how to say this but all I need is to find out how to code the yellow square and the lines around it on the bottom right of this image:  http://imgur.com/GmUw8pk                                                                             I thank you for your work and time that you have put into this.